# Aurelia dependency injection when instantiating objects

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, aurelia

If I create a supporting class, e.g. UserList that has HttpClient injected it into it, then whoever instantiates that class will have to pass an HttpClient object to it in the constructor. Shouldn't the @inject(HttpClient) take care of getting the HttpClient singleton and injecting it into the constructor? Otherwise every class that needs to refererence UserList will also have get a reference to HttpClient so that it can then pass it to the UserList constructor (and defeating the purpose of injection).

UserList.ts

```
@inject(HttpClient)
export class UserList {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient){
    }
...
}
```

DoSomething.ts

```
export class DoSomething {
    userList: UserList;

    constructor(){
         this.userList = new UserList(); //doesn't work without passing HttpClient
    }
}
```

to make this work I have to get a reference to HttpClient in the DoSomething class even though it won't be using it directly. The working version which seems to be poorly implemented:

DoSomething.ts

```
@inject(HttpClient)
export class DoSomething {
    userList: UserList;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient){
         this.userList = new UserList(http); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you import `inject` ? `import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';`

Comment: The problem in the code you posted is that you aren't holding on to a reference to `HttpClient` in `UserList`. In any case, JamesCarters answer below is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to handle this is to use a `Factory` Resolver

```
import { Factory } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Factory.of(UserList))
export class DoSomething {

    userList: UserList;

    constructor(UserList) {

        // this is a factory, so you call the function without new
        this.userList = UserList();
    }
}

@inject(HttpClient)
export class UserList {

    http: HttpClient;

    constructor(HttpClient) {
        this.http = HttpClient;
    }
}
```

For more information see the answer given in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524589/use-validation-on-class-object-without-injection-in-aurelia/37530332#37530332), or the [official docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/3).

Comment: if this answer is helpful to you, please upvote and accept

Comment: You're the man. Thanks for answering my main.js qurelia.container question too!

Comment: There is no need to use the Factory.  Just inject as the answers below describe.

Answer (score 9):

If you use typescript, don't worry about this.
Use @autoinject and see magic happen!

Like this:

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject()
export class UserList {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    }
...
}
```

In other file:

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject()
export class DoSomething {
    constructor(private userList: UserList){
    }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler will emit the type metadata and Aurelia will read this injecting instances on correct way!

More information about: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/dependency-injection/1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/doc/article/dependency-injection-basics

Comment: Thank's Ashley Grant, best practices ever!

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject the UserList in DoSomething

```
import {UserList} from 'where-ever-user-list-is';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(UserList)
export class DoSomething {
    userList: UserList;

    constructor(userList){
         this.userList = userList
    }
}
```

Comment: or do `container.get(UserList)` instead of `new`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Aurelia `dependency injection`, you need to import the required modules:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class DoSomething{

    constructor(http){
        // do your stuff
    }

}
```

This is the *ES6* implementation, the one I use, but I believe all you need to change is the `type` in the `constructor`.